# Doubt in Proof of Boundedness for Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

By now, it has been established that the image of a continuous function over a closed bounded interval is also bounded. The proof given below aims to show that the maximum value is attained at some point, within the bounded interval.

> By the earlier result, $\,f$ is bounded. Consider the image of $[a,b]$ under $f$: $$A = f([a,b]) = \left\{f(x) : x \in [a,b]\right\}.$$
>   $f$ bounded means that $A$ is bounded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. We also have that $A\neq \emptyset$.
>
> Since $A$ is bounded and non-empty, there is a supremum: $M=\sup A$. Given any positive integer $n$, $M-1/n$ cannot be an upper bound for $A$. Then there exists some $x_n \in [a,b]$ such that
>   $$M-\frac{1}{n} < f(x_n) \leq M. \tag{$*$}$$
>   By Bolzano-Weierstrass, $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_{j}} \to x$. Since $a\leq x_{n_{j}}\leq b$, $a\leq x\leq b$. By the continuity of $f$, $\,f(x_{n_{j}}) \to f(x)$. But by $(*)$, $\,f(x_{n_{j}}) \to M$. By the uniqueness of the limit, $\,f(x)=M$.

**My problem** is with the line marked $(*)$, *what in the world **guarantees the existence** of $x_n$ such that $M-\frac{1}{n} < f(x_n) \leq M$?*

Please help me understand the proof, thanks!

Comment: You should replace "bounded interval" by "closed bounded interval".

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: For example $(a,b)$ is a bounded interval but the result fails for $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole argument is actually contained in the proof. Since $M - \frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound, there must be an element larger than that, say $f(x_n)$. On the other hand, $f(x_n) \leq M$ because $M$ is an upper bound.

Comment: So the essence of this argument does lie in the fact that the function f **can attain all values in the interval infA to supA**, where A = image of [a, b] in function f, right?

Comment: What you say indeed holds by the intermediate value theorem, but is not used here. By definition every element $y \in A$ is of the form $y = f(x)$. Maybe it is clearer to say there must be an element **in $\textbf{A}$** that is larger than $M - \frac{1}{n}$ and since every element in $A$ is of that form, we can call that element $f(x_n)$.

Comment: +1 for your comment and +1 for your answer. The idea of a supremum is simple but often people forget to apply its definition properly.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose no such  $x_n $ exists for some  $n \in\mathbb N$. Then  $f (x)\leq M-\frac1n $ for all $x\in [a,b] $, contradicting the assumption  that $\sup A=M $.